# Title of column/standard metadata links to list where metadata are managed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, metadata, hyperlink

For a starting up site I would love to ad a link in the table to the location where I manage the metadata from that column (I use a lookup column, so the source is a list)

The goal is to give my colleagues the opportunity to add items to the list when needed, but to spare them the time to actually having to search the location of this list.

Since I have quite a bit of lists, I don't like to just add these links randomly ... I would prefer thet title of the column to be an hyperlink, or otherwise the standard metadata.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What works for me now is to add the hyperlink to the description field. This way, people don't have to search and automatically go to the right list to add their details!